# Converting 2 columned .txt of doubles into 2 arrays and reading them

Tags: c

I have a .txt file that consists of two columns of floats. The first column has values of the variable A, and the second for B.

> 1.0 2.0
>
> 1.0 3.0
>
> [There are no spaces between ROWS, I had to write it as so here because it wouldn't show up otherwise.]

I have to use these numbers to solve this equation for C:

A_{j} + B_{j+1}(X) = C

Aj = the jth term of A (aka the jth row term), j+1 would be the term after that.

I want to go through the whole text file, for different j's. Lets assume j goes up to 10, so 10 rows in the .txt.

```
int j;
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
  C = A[j] + B[j+1]*X;
```

As you can see my plan is to convert these columns into two arrays. 1 for A and 1 for B.

If I read the text like this:

```
void readAB(double *A, double *B) {
    FILE *infile;
    
    if(2!=fscanf(infile,"%lf %lf", A, B)) {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(1);
        
    }
    fclose(infile);
}
```

All I know so far is to call in int_main like this:

```
double A;
double B;
readAB(&A,&B);
```

But how do I call it, convert it into an array to be used later on?

Answer (score 0):

Read directly into the arrays

```
void readAB(double *A, double *B, int n, FILE * infile)) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
       fscanf(infile,"%lf %lf", &A[i], &B[i]);
```

and so on

Caller should be:

```
FILE * infile = fopen(...);
int n = countlines(infile);
fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_SET);
double *A = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
double *B = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
readAB(A, B, n, infile);
```

where countlines reads the file, just counting lines.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding you but I don't have arrays yet. I just have floats in columns.

Comment: Why read one-by-one when you want arrays?  Pass two arrays to the routine.

Comment: I'm a bit new to C sorry. Does "fscanf(infile,"%lf %lf", &A[i], &B[i]);" make two arrays called A and B? I thought you would need to do malloc to make an array

Comment: I updated the answer.  The caller needs to declare the arrays.

Comment: I don't have any arrays in my .txt I want to make them. And I don't know the length of the array for certain until it's made. The .txt file I wrote above would be length 2, but the file could change and be length 4, 7, 88 etc.

Comment: do you have an upper bound on size?

Comment: @mgfee you ned to dynamically allocate memory as you do not know the size of the file.

Comment: Simplest way if you don't know the size is to read the file once to get the size, allocate the arrays, then read again to populate.

Answer (score 0):

to have it done dynamically (ie if you do not know how many lines the text file has)

```
#define MALLOC_STEP     32
#define MAXLINE         256

typedef struct
{
    size_t datapos;
    size_t buffsize;
    double data[];
}data_t;

int myrealloc(data_t **data)
{
    if(!*data || !(*data) -> buffsize || ((*data) -> datapos == (*data) -> buffsize - 1))
    {
        size_t newbuffsize = !*data ? MALLOC_STEP : (*data) -> buffsize + MALLOC_STEP;
        data_t *tmpbuff = realloc(*data, sizeof(**data) + newbuffsize * sizeof((*data) -> data[0]));
        if(!tmpbuff) return -1;
        if(newbuffsize == MALLOC_STEP) tmpbuff -> datapos = 0;
        tmpbuff -> buffsize = newbuffsize;
        *data = tmpbuff;
    }
    return 0;
}

int readNext(FILE *fp, data_t **data1, data_t **data2)
{
    char line[MAXLINE];

    if(fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp) == NULL) return -1;
    if(myrealloc(data1) || myrealloc(data2)) return 1;
    if(sscanf(line, "%lf %lf", &((*data1) -> data[(*data1) -> datapos]), &((*data2) -> data[(*data2) -> datapos])) != 2) return -1;
    (*data1) -> datapos++;
    (*data2) -> datapos++;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    data_t *arr1 = NULL, *arr2 = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    int result;

    // create test data
    if(fp)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "34563.5674  5654634.233445\n");
        fprintf(fp, "34563.5674e-45  5654634.233445e1\n");
        fprintf(fp, "34563.5674e45  5654634.233445\n");
        fprintf(fp, "34563.5674e10  5654634.233445e3\n");

        fclose(fp);
    }
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if(fp)
    {
        do
        {
            result = readNext(fp, &arr1, &arr2);
        }while(!result);

        printf("Datapos %u, Out numbers are:\n", arr1 -> datapos);
        for(size_t index = 0; index < arr1 -> datapos; index++)
        {
            printf("row %04u arr1 = %lg, \t\tarr2 = %lg\n", index, arr1 -> data[index], arr2 -> data[index]);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
}
```

you can easily play with it yourself https://godbolt.org/z/9giuWS